Is there a history of Canadian soldiers in Northern Ireland during WW2?
I can’t find any history of Canadian Soldiers being in Northern Ireland during WW2, yet my Canadian father married my Irish mum in Belfast in Dec 1943. My Dad died in 1965 when I was 13, now at the age of 72 I’m finally mature enough to ask the question. Unfortunately the few relatives I have are unable to provide any answer.

Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s). At a minimum, all questions should explain why Wikipedia is insufficient.

Quite possibly they met elsewhere but returned to her family home for the wedding, as would be normal at that time.

You should be able to request access to the military service files of your father at Library and Archives Canada, through an ATIP request.

https://www.bbc.co.uk/bitesize/articles/z6cwh4j#zswxvj6 Has lots of info. What service was your father in? If navy he could well have been stationed there, if army could well have been there for a while in transit.

what would canadian soldiers be doing in northern ireland during world war 2 and why?
